# Django "cannot import name Member"

Tags: django, import

I am struggling with this error. There had been a model named Member, but I have now removed all reference to it, deleted and remade the database – I searched project but found no reference to 'Member' at all! This is a completely new project so there's not much in there (I could start again but I need to know what's going on).

Please help, thanks!

```
ImportError at /admin
cannot import name Member
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name Member
Exception Location:     

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
    Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/methuselah/code/django/ss',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-0.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Wed, 16 May 2012 13:13:47 +0100
```

Comment: Do make sure you've removed all pyc files.

Comment: Thanks you sir, that's great. How can I have django ignore those files or something? I surely don't need to remove them with every change?

Comment: If you're using the `manage.py runserver` command to run django, then it usually just works correctly. I wonder if you had a pyc file with no py file which was causing this problem.

Comment: that could've been the problem. i'll pay attention to this stuff from now on. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either clear your .pyc files, which are the compiled versions of your data, or you can restart your python app server and it should recompile everything for you.

Comment: I had actually restarted the server but it didn't seem to recompile. Do you know why that is?

Comment: When you say you restarted the server, do you mean the app server or the web server? If you have something like gunicorn or whatever else running your django instance, then you will need to restart that, rather than apache or whatever your webserver is. This depends a lot on your setup.

Comment: this is local dev so just the django shell server

Comment: @Jordan It will recompile only if it has both `py` and `pyc` files. If it has only `pyc` file with no corresponding `py`, it should be deleted manually.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I figured he removed it from an overall models.py file, which of course could be a bad assumption.